# C# How to Detect excel 2003 professional edition is installed?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

How can we check whether excel 2003 professional edition is installed on users machine?

I can detect Whether excel 2003 is installed or not using registry key.

If below registry key is exist then excel 2003 is installed in user machine.

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Excel
```

But Now, I want to detect whether installed excel 2003 is professional edition or not. So is there any way to do same.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this in registry key:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths

or

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
>
> Version numbers are:

7.0 -97

8.0 - 98

9.0 -2000

10.0 -2002

11.0 -2003

12.0 -2007

14.0 -2010

You can also check here:

> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\VERSION\Common\InstallRoot

Where **VERSION** is the version of Office you are looking for.

**EDIT: Answering to your comment.**

**You can get the product version (Standard or Professional) by querying
the installed software with WMI:**

```
 ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product");
                foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
                {
                if (mo["Name"] != null)
                {
                    string ProductName = mo["Name"].ToString();
                }

            }
```

This will get you the product version of all installed software, just search office entry
and you should get the package name that appears in control panel.

[image]

Comment: But how can I detect whether Installed excel version standard edition of 2003 or professional edition of 2003 like that.

Comment: I updated my answer, check how you can get standard or professional version